# Meteor JS Publication

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to remove any document before publishing. Can we achieve this using transform or any other way?

My Publication function -

```
Meteo.publish('projects', function() {
  return Projects.find({});
});
```

Above publication function will fetch all data but can we fetch only selected data?

Comment: Do you mean to filter data using e.g. specific field?

Comment: @mparkitny Yes by any field but not using the query because I've to compare some values to other collection as well. Thanks!!